# Task Canceled While Creating Order

Tags: virtocommerce

When creating a new order I am seeing long execution times and then it finally fails with a TaskCanceledException.

I'm using my own payment module and I've compared it to one's written already and I seem to be implementing things right. The payment is being processed.

https://github.com/montanehamilton/vc-module-PayPal-Rest

I do have a custom shipping method module as well

https://github.com/montanehamilton/vc-fedex

Any thought's on where to look when encountering this behavior? Running 2.13.9 of the platform.

### Exception Details

POST storefrontapi/cart/createorder 500 Internal Server Error A task was canceled.

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
 at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.AutoRestClients.OrdersModuleApi.OrderModule.d__9.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.AutoRestClients.OrdersModuleApi.OrderModuleExtensions.d__9.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
 at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Controllers.Api.ApiCartController.d__21.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks were getting canceled due to timeouts. The VirtoCommerce storefront should be configured to set these timeouts to a value appropriate for the task.

In my case PayPal recommends at least 30 seconds, if not more. I set the timeout to 1 minute and the problem was resolved.

You can set the AppSetting with name "VirtoCommerce:Storefront:ApiRequest:Timeout" in your web.config to change the timeout when making API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend update platform to 2.13.11 and modules to latest version.

The update reduced Memory Usage and performance during order flow, so we can decrease Azure price plan.

Comment: Good to know, I'm at 2.13.14 now. PayPal is still taking forever to process so setting the timeout is my only hope till I can get better response from PayPal.